# Culture name 'es-419' is not supported. (.NET 2.0)

Tags: .net, vb.net, iis, cultureinfo, culture

We have an old .NET 2.0 website that threw a strange error today.
When users try to access the website with their region settings set to Spanish (Latin America) the site crashes and displays following error:

[image: Error]

After doing some googling I found that this error is most likely because the .NET 2.0 framework doesn't support the es-419 culture as this was added later.
But what I didn't find is how to fix it.

I tried changing the globalization settings (now set to auto) to invariant language but that didn't seem to help.

Anyone of you guys know how to fix this one?

EDIT: Fixed by making a custom culture on the web server with the code 'es-419'.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Why do you even have a website targeting .NET 2.0?

Comment: @VisualVincent It's an old website that needs maintenance until the new one is finished (which is in development).